# Applying Filter And Finding The Last Cell - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

```
Sub test_sum()
last_row_in_Process_sheet = Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
atmCurrentSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9,Range("AQ3:AQ4533"))
MsgBox last_row_in_Process_sheet
MsgBox atmCurrentSum
End Sub
```

Above data is filtered data, When queried for last used cell in column "A" .I am getting "A232" but i need result as "A255".

which function do i need to use here?

I need to get total of filtered cell on AQ255 for COLUMN AQ

Comment: So your question is: "How do I find the last used row in my spreadsheet, even if it is hidden?"

Comment: It actually works for me. Are you sure there is data in `a255`?

Comment: row 255 in your picture is empty, do you want to find last used, or first empty line?

Comment: first empty cell.

Comment: Is there actually any data in rows 233 to 254? If not, it worked as it got the last row? Or do you want the last non-hidden row?

Comment: How your last sentence is related to your original question? it seems to be another question, please stick to your original question, if you have also other questions please post them separately

Answer (score 1):

Finding first empty row in excel in easiest way is with `UsedRange`
`ActiveSheet.Usedrange.Rows.Count+1`

(if your data doesn't start in first row, then use:
`ActiveSheet.Usedrange.Row + ActiveSheet.Usedrange.Rows.Count`)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data into a table. Then it works.

- Activate the `insert` ribon (menu)
- Select `table`
- Indicate your data already has headers
- Enter

To be honest, I call this a bug in Excel.

If you need the first empty cell instead of the last non-empty one, apply an offset of 1 row

```
last_row_in_Process_sheet = Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Row
```

Comment: i need out put as "A255" but your function gives me 233 as the "output"